# Facing issue while installing opentaps

Tags: java, opentaps

I am trying to install opentaps-1.5.0 on a Windows machine, Java version 1.7.0_45.
Getting an error

> C:\opentaps-1.5.0>"\bin\java" -Xms512M - Xms1536M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -jar ofbiz.jar 1>runtime\logs\console.cog
>   Syatem cannot find the path specified`

Answer (score -1):

try java version 1.6.... opentaps supports java1.5 or java1.6...
also you have to set java path("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6"...inmy case) in the systems environment variable ...

check this link..
http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/General_Installation_of_Opentaps

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: what other links should i post... ?